# Connected to Unknown Database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is my connection string in web.config:

[image]

Note database name isn't there in connection string, but I can perform all CRUD operations using EF in MVC 5.

Can someone tell how I can get to which database I am connected in MSSQL Server.

[image: Get return in Code]

Comment: `SSMS -> Object Explorer -> Security -> Logins -> sa -> right click -> check default database`

Comment: can you please add this as comment, so that i can mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check default database using `SQL Server Management Studio`:

`Object Explorer -> Server -> Security -> Logins -> sa -> right click -> check default database`

Something like:

[image]

<sup>Image source: http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Fix-cannot-open-user-default-database-Login-failed-Login-failed-for-user-SQL-Server-Error/</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As per @lad2025's comment, because the connection string has omitted the Database (or `Initial Catalog`) definition, so the connection will default to the default database assigned to the login used to connect to the server (`sa` in your case).

There are a number of ways to find the database

- As suggested in the comment, determine the default mapping for the user
- Or, once your app has an active connection, run `sp_who` (as you already have `sa` access) and look up the `dbname` column for the connection.

You should however address this behaviour:

- defaulting the database on the server in this way is fragile, as e.g. the DBA could change the default database
- Never let an app use `sa` as a login. The login should be restricted to the minimum set of accesses required